# Can an open port be hacked to get access to the command line?

Tags: command-line, security, http, port

Assume I run a custom app on an arbitrary port on a linux box - let's say 7890.

This is a go language web server. Runs an app on top of HTTP. No HTTPS. It runs as a dedicated but "normal" user with no sudo rights. The firewall rule for this port allows "everyone (world)"  to access it.

All ssh access is secured and firewall rules allow only access via a set of known IPs. SSH access is configured to allow only key-based access.

Is this enough information to answer the following questions:

- Can an attacker ever gain access to the command line via that exposed port?
- If the previous question can be answered with "yes, if...", what are the most important things I need to take care of so that the app can't be exploited to get access to the box?

The assumption would be that there are no other known security holes.

Obviously I am no security expert. I hope this is enough information to give an informed statement. I assume there are myriads of related issues and no "absolute" yes/no can be given, but maybe some rough idea is enough for me to get an idea.

Thanks.

Comment: IMHO, without a _specific_ example application, answers would have to say "yes" to the first question (because saying "no" can't ever be proven), and the second question would need a seminar series' worth of material to answer in the general case.  In short, the question is far too broad.

Comment: Yeah, I am not shocked about this answer...Thank you nonetheless

Comment: Actually there is an important learning here for me - even if it sounds stupid, it means I need to go check myself deeper at all levels of the app - because there is no way to say it's not possible. 

I am taking over an app and that is why I was asking.

Comment: Check the "normal" user's entries in `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/groups`, `/etc/sudoers`. Read `man -a passwd;man sudo sudoers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can an attacker ever gain access to the command line via that exposed port?

If there are vulnerabilities in your app, yes.

> what are the most important things I need to take care of so that the app can't be exploited to get access to the box?

That's a very difficult question.

- *Go* is a pretty safe language, so ostensibly the app can only be hacked if you have issues with the application logic
- To add an extra layer of security you can use 1) systemd features to [limit](https://gist.github.com/ageis/f5595e59b1cddb1513d1b425a323db04) what the daemon can do 2) write a SeLinux/Apparmor policy 3) run the daemon in chroot/virtualized [environment](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-nspawn) 4) run it under `docker` or any other lightweight userspace container/hyperviser

Comment: Makes sense. Sorry for the very broad question, you made a best effort to answer, thanks.